# Удаление файла в docker контейнере удаляет файл в проекте

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Имеется `django` проект, запускаю его через `docker-compose` (сам проект `django` + база `postgres`). Если после запуска зайти в контейнер и удалить там файл (например старый файл базы `sqlite3`), то он почему-то удалится не только в контейнере, но и в самом проекте. Т.е. внутри контейнера оказывается не копия проекта, а просто линк на файлы самого проекта на рабочем компьютере. Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку в настройках.
Вот `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-dev pkg-config cifs-utils libengine-gost-openssl1.1 curl gnupg2 && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip poetry && poetry config virtualenvs.create false

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry install --no-root --no-dev

COPY ./backend .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
```

Вот `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --workers=2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 backend.wsgi
    container_name: django
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - "8060:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Ну так volumes монтирует, а не копирует. Т.е. ты сначала скопировал файлы, а потом поверх зачем-то смонтировал их же.

Comment: Упустил этот момент. Похоже для web volume мне монтировать не требуется. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках web, как правильно заметил Alexey Ten, необходимо было удалить

```
volumes:
  - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
```

Данный volume был лишний (не требуется мне на текущий момент), а именно он заменял собой файлы, скопированные в контейнер.